# How to put equations and equivalence in Latex

Tags: equations, align

I am trying to put the following equation and equivalence in Latex, but I face with strange output, May you please help me to solve this issue:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
    (f_{uvw},f_{u_{1}v_{1}w_{1}})_{[u]([v][w])} & =f_{uvw}-f_{u_{1}v_{1}w_{1}} &\\
    &= [u]([v]([v_{1}][w_{1}]))-([u][v])([v_{1}][w_{1}])+([u]([v_{1}][w_{1}]))[v]\\
    &-[u]([v]([v_{1}][w_{1}]))+[u](([v][v_{1}])[w_{1}])-[u](([v][w_{1}])[v_{1}])&\\
    \equiv -(([u][v])[v_{1}])[w_{1}] + (([u][v])[w_{1}])[v_{1}] +(([u][v_{1}])[w_{1}])[v_{1}] \\
    & -(([u][w_{1}])[v_{1}])[v] + (([u][v])[v_{1}])[w_{1}] -(([u][v_{1}])[v])[w_{1}] \\
    &-(([u][w_{1}])[v])[v_{1}] + (([u][w_{1}])[v_{1}])[v]-(([u][v])[w_{1}])[v_{1}]  \\
    &+(([u][w_{1}])[v])[v_{1}] +(([u][v_{1}])[v])[w_{1}] _(([u][v_{1}])[w_{1}])[v_{1}] 
 \end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure you really need `flalign`; I find it's often a bit abused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't say what output you want but I guess you are missing one `&`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
    (f_{uvw},f_{u_{1}v_{1}w_{1}})_{[u]([v][w])} & =f_{uvw}-f_{u_{1}v_{1}w_{1}} &\\
    &= [u]([v]([v_{1}][w_{1}]))-([u][v])([v_{1}][w_{1}])+([u]([v_{1}][w_{1}]))[v]\\
    &-[u]([v]([v_{1}][w_{1}]))+[u](([v][v_{1}])[w_{1}])-[u](([v][w_{1}])[v_{1}])&\\
    \equiv
& 
-(([u][v])[v_{1}])[w_{1}] + (([u][v])[w_{1}])[v_{1}] +(([u][v_{1}])[w_{1}])[v_{1}] \\
    & -(([u][w_{1}])[v_{1}])[v] + (([u][v])[v_{1}])[w_{1}] -(([u][v_{1}])[v])[w_{1}] \\
    &-(([u][w_{1}])[v])[v_{1}] + (([u][w_{1}])[v_{1}])[v]-(([u][v])[w_{1}])[v_{1}]  \\
    &+(([u][w_{1}])[v])[v_{1}] +(([u][v_{1}])[v])[w_{1}] _(([u][v_{1}])[w_{1}])[v_{1}] 
 \end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Just for fun [!?], here's a refinement of David's approach. It adds a bit of extra vertical whitespace after rows 1 and 3, it provides indentation of the material in rows 3, 5, 6, and 7, and it fixes an issue with the material that's supposed to be in subscript in the final additive term in the final row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'flalign*' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
    (f_{uvw},f_{u_1 v_1 w_1})_{[u]([v][w])} 
    &= f_{uvw}-f_{u_1v_1w_1} \\[0.5ex]
    &=      [u]([v]([v_1][w_1]))-([u][v])([v_1][w_1])+([u]([v_1][w_1]))[v]\\
    &\quad -[u]([v]([v_1][w_1])) + [u](([v][v_1])[w_1]) -[u](([v][w_1])[v_1])\\[0.5ex]
    &\equiv-(([u][v])[v_1])[w_1] + (([u][v])[w_1])[v_1] +(([u][v_1])[w_1])[v_1] \\
    &\quad -(([u][w_1])[v_1])[v] + (([u][v])[v_1])[w_1] -(([u][v_1])[v])[w_1] \\
    &\quad -(([u][w_1])[v])[v_1] + (([u][w_1])[v_1])[v] -(([u][v])[w_1])[v_1]  \\
    &\quad +(([u][w_1])[v])[v_1] + (([u][v_1])[v])[w_1]_{(([u][v_1])[w_1])[v_1]}
 \end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some more fun with `fleqn` from `nccmath` and `multlined` from `mathtools`. I interpreted differently the code at the end of the last line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
  \begin{align*}
 & \mathrlap{ (f_{uvw},f_{u_{1}v_{1}w_{1}})_{[u]([v][w])} =f_{uvw}-f_{u_{1}v_{1}w_{1}}} \\
      & & & =\begin{multlined}[t] [u]([v]([v_{1}][w_{1}]))-([u][v])([v_{1}][w_{1}])+([u]([v_{1}][w_{1}]))[v]\\
    -[u]([v]([v_{1}][w_{1}]))+[u](([v][v_{1}])[w_{1}])-[u](([v][w_{1}])[v_{1}])\end{multlined}\\
   & & & \equiv
\begin{multlined}[t]
-(([u][v])[v_{1}])[w_{1}] + (([u][v])[w_{1}])[v_{1}] +(([u][v_{1}])[w_{1}])[v_{1}] \\
 -(([u][w_{1}])[v_{1}])[v] + (([u][v])[v_{1}])[w_{1}] -(([u][v_{1}])[v])[w_{1}] \\
-(([u][w_{1}])[v])[v_{1}] + (([u][w_{1}])[v_{1}])[v]-(([u][v])[w_{1}])[v_{1}] \\
+(([u][w_{1}])[v])[v_{1}] +(([u][v_{1}])[v])[w_{1}]-(([u][v_{1}])[w_{1}])[v_{1}]
\end{multlined}
 \end{align*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I see you interpreted the `_` (underscore) character in the last line as a typo and replaced it with `-`. Was this a hunch or did you actually understand the mathematics sufficiently to realize that `_` was a typo? Just curious.